# How to make a dimmer that doesn't depend on the load's resistance?

Tags: power-electronics, triac, dimmer, drill

I have an angle grinder which has a maximum power of 950 W.

My country provides 220 V as voltage source.

It has only one speed, so I want to make a dimmer to control its speed.

I used this circuit but it provides at least 130 VAC.

It makes the machine rotate very fast.

How can I make a dimmer to provide 0V?

[image]

Note: I used big heat sink.

Comment: You should use a phase control circuit with a triac. These have been around for 50 years, there are lots of circuits on the internet.

Comment: You don't use dimmers on motors!  That won't work and will set the motor on fire.  Use VFDs on motors.   Glad you asked first...

Comment: dimmers are fine on universal motors.  VFDs are needed for induction motors.

Comment: The 100nF capacitor seems too large. Google drill speed controller or buy one off eBayz as they as cheap.